# App Store Connect: "In-App Purchase and Subscriptions" section missing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I want to add subscriptions to my app in app store connect. The subscriptions status is "Waiting for Review". But the button "Submit for review" is greyed out.

On the subscriptions page I see this info:

> Your first subscription must be submitted with a new app version. Create your subscription, then select it from the app’s In-App Purchase and Subscriptions section on the version page before submitting the version to App Review. Learn More
>
> Once your binary has been uploaded and your first subscription has been submitted for review, additional subscriptions can be submitted from the Subscriptions section. Learn More

When I click on "learn more", I come to this page https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1986a0e5c

On the screenshot I see a "In-App Purchase and Subscriptions" section displayed under build. On my app is this section missing. How can I get this section?

My app is not released and not reviewed by apple. I cannot add the app to review because of the missing subscriptions in the app.

What do I missing to get the subscriptions work?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: I had to complete something in "agreements tax and banking". I called apple and they helped me to find this.

Answer (score 7):

I recently went through this and found that ALL THREE of the following must be true before the "In-App Purchase and Subscriptions" section will appear on the version page:

1. The app version submission must be in the “Prepare for Submission” state
2. There must be at least one IAP/subscription in the “Ready to Submit” state
3. All banking & agreements must set up and in place

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having this issue, all of the above information is correct, however in my case the Subscription was not fully complete.  Tapping on the Subscription - Group - Subscription and then at the very bottom is a section for a screenshot of your app and a comment that must be filled out in order for it to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already added the build for review (Add for review, not submit) the "In-App Purchase and Subscriptions" section is not visible. So, you have to remove build from review and "In-App Purchase and Subscriptions" section will be visible (if the status of subscriptions is Ready for Review).

Comment: My app is in the "Prepare for Submission" state (i.e. has not been added for review), and yet there is no "In-App Purchase and Subscriptions" section.